# How to replace, in a simple way, pairs of parentheses?

Tags: replace, parentheses

It would be useful for me to be able to replace, in a simple way, with simple emacs commands, parenthese pairs, like: (text text) [text text]  {text text} ...

How to do it?

Comment: Replace them with what? Also, can the pairs of (parens, braces, square brackets) be nested? Can you give an example of the most complicated replacement you are likely to need? Please edit your question and add to it as much information about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you, I would simply like to do this: select text in parentheses, change the type of parentheses in a pair, for example from (text text) to [text text], with a solution that allows you to choose the type of parentheses between () [] {} <> etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without any automation, I would do it like this:

```
(text text) -> [text text]
```

Assuming I have enabled `(electric-pair-mode)` and keybinded `(delete-pair)` to `C-c C-d`

1. `C-M-u` to go up to the opening `(`
2. `C-M-SPC` to select whole `(text text)`
3. `[` to enclose `[(text text)]`
4. `C-c C-d` to delete `(...)` pair

[image: asciicast]

It wouldn't work for `{...}` pair in emacs lisp mode, out of the box, but I guess it should be possible to setup as well -- I can see it works in c-mode, where I can change pairs `{...}` too.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll try. Of course, an automation that allows you to use all kinds of parentheses (or even quotes) would be great, but this is already an idea. thanks

Comment: @SalvoMicciché `C-M-u` is for "backward up the list", e.g. when you're inside `(` braces `)` and want to position cursor to the opening one. If your cursor is not inside, it usually echoes "at top level" and does nothing.

Comment: I tried, and it works. thanks.Something useful, at least. Then it is clear that it would be better to have an automation function that also gives the possibility to choose the type of inclusion (from () [] {} <> ``'' and so on)

Comment: thank you @Maxim Kim, I understood. It work